# Add Read Only Annotation on packaged global remote action method

Tags: apex, read-only

Can I add Read only annotation on the Global remote action method which is previously packaged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a test package and when i tried to add @readonly got this compile time error.

> Compile Error: Cannot add @ReadOnly to managed identifier

So we can not add annotations also on packaged global method. Salesforce also treats this as a change in method definition.